# mysql update multiplecolumns vs compare values in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, performance

Okay, talking millions of rows here..
Structure of like

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
some_data_before this| x_counter_total | y_counter_total | x_counter_week | y_counter_week | x_counter_year | y_counter_year
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   some_data_here... | 42142142....... | `241242142..... | 23214124...... | .............. | .............. |` ..............
```

And every of X and Y events to increment these columns  vs this

**EXAMPLE 2**

table A

```
some_data_before this| x_counter_total | y_counter_total |
----------------------------------------------------------
some_data_here...... | 42142142....... | `241242142..... |
```

table B

```
  key_connected_with_table_A | x_event | y_event | occured_timestamp
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
 id 21...................... |  true   | false   |  current_timestamp
```

My need is this. I need number of X and Y events in some time, past day/week/month/year etc.
My question is that Is it better to update(increment) multiple columns describing the time period i need,  like in EXAMPLE 1 or is it better to
on each Event add a Row like in EXAMPLE 2 and then count total VOTES with same ID WHERE occured_timestamp - current_timestamo < TIMESTAMP_OF_A_WEEK for example. Which one is more efficient? talking millions of records, and thousands of request in a  minute.

Comment: It is better not to splay that stuff across columns.

Answer (score 0):

NO, I would keep them in a single table since then I would need to fire only one `UPDATE` statement but if you separate them to 2 tables then either you will need to execute 2 update statement (or) create a `AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER` to insert into the other table (or) probably do a update join to update all the respective values ion both tables which to me looks more performance hit than having all the columns in single table.